# Understanding Protocols and Sub-Classing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, protocols

I am in the process of creating a UITableViewController sub-class (call it "MyTableViewClass", that would ultimately be sub-classed for specific table view controllers (call it "MySpecificTableViewClass".  Ideally I want some methods that are in the MySpecificTableViewClass to be "required" ie. have the developer interface say "implementation is not complete".  Is there a way to do that without having to declare in the protocol in MyTableViewClass?

MyTableViewClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MyTableViewClass;
@protocol MyTableViewClassProtocol <NSObject>;

-(void) fooBar;
@end

@interface MyTableViewClass : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, MyTableViewClassProtocol>
....
```

This will indicate in my implementation of MyTableViewClass that I have "forgotten" to implement fooBar.  I think I can just handle that with a stub method (is that the best way?).

MySpecificTableViewClass.h

```
....
#import "MyTableViewClass.h"

@interface MySpecificTableViewClass : MyTableViewClass
....
```

In the implementation of MySpecificTableViewClass - no warning shows that I am missing

```
-(void) fooBar
```

If I change MySpecificTableViewClass.h to

```
....
#import "MyTableViewClass.h"

@interface MySpecificTableViewClass : MyTableViewClass <MyTableViewClassProtocol>
....
```

Then I do get the warning, but **remembering** to define the protocol, seems counter intuative, or am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a great way to implement this other than to put in stubs and call `NSAssert()` in them to catch (at runtime) any unimplemented methods. Objective-C doesn't have the concept of an abstract class.

That said, and while I've used this pattern myself, often it is better to rethink your design and use the Strategy pattern and protocols. That is, instead of having an abstract `MyTableViewClass`, create a `MyTableViewHandler` that is a subclass of `NSObject` and contains whatever special logic you need. Then your table view controllers can be direct subclasses of `UITableViewController` and delegates of `MyTableViewHandler`. As a delegate, the protocol can be enforced. And this creates a simpler and more flexible object model. It's not always appropriate, and abstract classes have their place, but do consider the Strategy pattern before you jump to pure inheritance. It often works better.

Comment: I understand now.  For now I have just done what you describe in paragraph 1 (except that I used NSException) to bad there is no way to make the developer environment see this before run-time.  Your solution of paragraph 2 certainly seems more elegant, but for now, since I have most of the code already done by subclassing UITableViewController this will do.

Answer (score 0):

As MyTableViewClass is already implementing the protocol, its subclasses will get those implementations available for them, It means subclasses are also kind of implementing them. You can change/extend the implementations in your subclasses.